# Using existing python objects and functions in a GUI with custom code

Tags: python, gui, dataflow

Let's say there are multiple existing python objects and functions that I want to initiate via a GUI and input some custom code to work with them.

For example:

`Obj1` and `Obj2` are two instances of a class which have an attribute `.value`. `f1` and `f2` are some functions. These classes and functions already exist in some python file `src.py` I have locally.

Now, I want my students to be able to initiate as many of these instances (Obj1, Obj2) objects as they like, code some rule-based (custom) system, and then execute these functions (f1, f2).

A simple rule would, for example, be:
If `Obj1.value` is larger than `Obj2.value`, execute `f1`, else, execute `f2`.

[image]

What simple to use graphical software would make sense for this sort of thing? The custom code would not necessarily have to be in python, but since it is quite simple, that would be favourable.

I think this would be possible with *Apache Nifi* or *Node-RED* (not sure!). Is it also realisable (without weeks of effort) using *tkinter*?

Additional info which might be relevant:
The class of which the instances are called `Obj1` and `Obj2` contain MQTT subscriptions, so the `.value` is getting updated frequently. The functions `f1` would make API POST requests and `f2` would write a value into a database.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Boa Constrictor]http://boa-constructor.sourceforge.net/). Also, Google - I can't remember the name, but a few years back I found several free apps which would generate a GUI if your Python code uses `argparse`.

Aha, Google says [Gooey](https://www.pakstech.com/blog/python-gooey/) (see also [here](https://codeburst.io/how-to-use-the-easiest-gui-of-your-life-in-python-d3762270a2a0)).

***Possibly*** https://github.com/codypiersall/cligui, although, on its GitHub page, the author himself says "Tell people to look at Gooey".

I am sure that there was at east one more, but can't find it at the moment.

Do you use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html)? If not, you should.